# Why doesn’t my jQuery code update live image loaded in a video element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I have an URL of a live image and I want to display it as a video, but only first frame is show instead of an animation. I use Google Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125.

What am I missing?

```
<video id="one_frame_per_second"
       autoplay=autoplay 
       poster="http://ip.address/screensaver/now.jpeg"></video>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#one_frame_per_second').show();

        mtimer = setInterval(function() {
            $('#one_frame_per_second').attr(
                'poster',
                'http://ip.address/screensaver/now.jpeg'
            );
        }, 15);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're setting the same `poster` attribute every 15 milliseconds, why?

Comment: Because `http://ip.address/screensaver/now.jpeg` is JPEG image but live updates so i need to render it every 15 mili sec to get latest image in seamless mode.

Comment: Is this a BUG??? Why its not updating the latest version of the now.jpeg?

Comment: In previous versions of Google Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 this was working fine. Some nonsense removed it or broken it.

Comment: Have a live example for us to use? It's hard to debug without one.

Comment: @ZachSaucier: YES Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/ajn5ntcj/3/ , http://jsfiddle.net/ajn5ntcj/  , http://jsfiddle.net/Lnpctb4w/  none is working with Google Chrome latest and Google Canary but with old Google Chrome version it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please report Google Chrome, Canary, Opera, Firefox to solve this feature which was working in past.

Temporary solution is:

```
<video id="one_frame_per_second"
       autoplay=autoplay 
       poster="http://82.143.92.19/video/now.jpeg" ></video>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $( "#one_frame_per_second" ).show();              
      var mtimer=setInterval(function(){  
         $("#one_frame_per_second").attr('poster', 'http://82.143.92.19/video/now.jpeg?r'+Date.now());
       },150);      
  });

</script>
```

NOTE: ?r= Date.Now() , caching issue + minimal interval time

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide this live image so that we can test, or a working jsfiddle?

Without further knowledge, I would guess it's because you're setting the same source.

Can you try this instead:

```
   mtimer=setInterval(function(){  
    var video = $("#one_frame_per_second");      
    video.attr('poster', '');
    video.attr('poster', 'http://ip.address/screensaver/now.jpeg');
  },15);
```

Comment: I tried your example with Google Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 and Google Canary but still same. But when i use less then Google Chrome version 36 same code of mine or yours works.

Comment: can you provide a working example (or one that should be working)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ajn5ntcj/ - not working with Google 36 but works with old Google

Answer (score 1):

Try first constructing the function and then calling it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#one_frame_per_second" ).show();              

  var mtimer = function() {setInterval(function(){        
    $("#one_frame_per_second").attr('poster', 'http://ip.address/screensaver/now.jpeg');  
  },15); }

  mtimer
});
```

Also, if you are still getting error, try increasing the timer to something like 10000 and do a `console.log($("#one_frame_per_second").attr('poster', 'http://ip.address/screensaver/now.jpeg');  )` inside the timer to see if you are getting any weird error

**Update**

Ok i think i got it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ajn5ntcj/3/

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $( "#one_frame_per_second" ).show();              
      var mtimer= function(){
        var video_t = $("#one_frame_per_second");      
        //video_t.attr('poster', '')
        video_t.attr('poster', 'http://82.143.92.19/video/now.jpeg')
        //console.log('here im again2')
      }
      setInterval(mtimer,1000)
      //console.log('here im again')
  });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ajn5ntcj/ - please see this works with old Google but does not work with Latest Google chrome and canary

Comment: NO - not working if you test with Google Chrome latest version and Google Canary http://jsfiddle.net/ajn5ntcj/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think its help  :

```
 <video id="one_frame_per_second"
       autoplay=autoplay 
       poster="http://82.143.92.19/video/now.jpeg" ></video>



     $(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#one_frame_per_second" ).show();              
  var mtimer= function(){
    var video_t = $("#one_frame_per_second");      
    video_t.attr('poster', 'http://82.143.92.19/video/now.jpeg')
    //console.log('here im again2')
  }
  setInterval(mtimer,1000)
```

});